# msys2 doesn't find mingw64

Tags: windows, mingw, msys2

I downloaded:

https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/mingw-builds

https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/msys2

and installed them under `C:/development/msys64`. Under this folder I find the msys2.exe and the mingw64 folder, which in turn contains the bin one with all the mingw executable.

I added `C:/development/msys64/mingw64/bin` folder to the PATH env var.
In fact from a Windows prompt I can invoke the gcc - for example. Instead inside the msys2 shell I cannot find them. I mean, they are in `/mingw64/bin` but they are not available at prompt.

I'm sure I missed some steps!

Comment: I "fixed" adding to the local env var PATH `/mingw64/bin` and copying gcc.exe to cc.exe in the same folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MSYS2 has packages for its own GCC toolchains and you would probably be better off using those toolchains instead of downloading a different one.   For example, to use a 64-bit MinGW GCC, you would have to run `pacman -S x86_64-w64-mingw32-toolchain` and then make sure you are starting MSYS2 using the "MinGW-w64 64-bit Shell" shortcut (or something like that) so that `/mingw64/bin` is on your PATH.

Also, MSYS2 does not respect your system or user environment variables; it uses its own PATH by default.

Comment: Hi, I ran into the same confusion. I installed MinGW-w64 first and MSYS2 later to find the folder structure in msys installation directory for mingw32 and 64. And then I edited "/etc/fstab" and got msys to find mingw. Is it ok to do so?
What do you suppose I shall do?
Also, I installed MSYS because make tool wasn't available in MinGW-w64.

Comment: I would not edit fstab, I would use the official MSYS2 toolchains that you can install with pacman unless there is a really good reason to use a different toolchain.

Answer (score 16):

**Method to switch from MinGW-w32 to MinGW-w64**

- <s>[Download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download) the executable file of MinGW-w64</s> Refer the EDIT

(Executable file link may change for future releases, this is for Version 8.1.0, Kindly cross verify the latest version before installing from this link)

- Installation Process (In Settings):

```
Version: PICK LATEST
Architecture: x86_64
Threads: posix
Exception: seh
```

**If anyone is trying to add MinGW-w64 as a PATH variable and is not able to find the `gdb.exe` in `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`, <s>try looking for it in the Program files</s>.**

<s>`C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin`</s>

<s>The `gdb.exe` and other files are located in this directory.</s>

---

EDIT:

After making some changes in the launch.json file in VSCode, the MinGW-w64 GDB debugger started giving errors because there was 2 versions of MinGW in different folders i.e, MINGW and mingw64!

**It is essential that the installation path does not contain any spaces

(i.e., space in *"Program Files"*), this will create conflicts later.**

STEPS:

**1.** Uninstalled all the versions of GCC that was installed in the PC - Cygwin, MSYS2(32 bit) and mingw64(64 bit) and installed the MinGW-w64 again, this time using the MSYS2.

Please start afresh, if debugger is giving errors and if versions are clashing!

**2.** [Download](https://www.msys2.org/) the MSYS2 installer from this link.

Install process is simple, follow the steps mentioned in the website!

> ***It is essential that the installation path does not contain any spaces. Therefore, we cannot install MinGW-w64 in `Program Files`.***

**3.** After Installation is complete: Open MSYS2 terminal *(`pink icon`)*.

Update the package database and base packages using:

```
pacman -Syu
```

After this, Update rest of the base packages using:

```
pacman -Su
```

**4.** Now switch over to MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit terminal *(`blue icon`)*.

To install gcc and g++ for C and C++.

> For 64 bit:
>
> ```
> pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
> ```

To install debugger (gdb).

> For 64 bit:
>
> ```
> pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb
> ```

**5.** Now you're all SET!

Check versions:

```
gcc --version
g++ --version
gdb --version
```

**6.** Finally, remove the old environment variables if any are left and add the new environment variable to the PATH!

**BEFORE DEBUGGING FILES IN VSCode, MAKE SURE TO ADD `-g` tag while building, otherwise breakpoints will be ignored by the debugger!**

**Footnote:**
It's very important to keep all the versions in one folder, if folders are different, then life will get tough later!

Comment: If `gdb.exe` is not in `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`, it means you forgot to install its package (`mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb`). As the other answer says, mixing MSYS2 with other MinGW distributions usually doesn't end well.

Comment: This worked for me! The other answers did not! When installing from the .exe file, the gdb.exe is created inside the Program Files instead of C:\msys64\mingw64\bin folder. I was looking for it for about an hour, finally found it in the Program Files! Now finally my g++ version is 64 bit after setting it as the PATH variable. I thought it might help someone in the future, that's why I posted it as an answer here. As you said mixing MYSY2 with other MinGW distributions usually doesn't end well. Thanks for your input! I appreciate it!

Comment: In my case, it was because of the **Blue Icon**

Answer (score -1):

the correct path is
C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin
not
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin as given [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_check-your-mingw-installation)

Comment: Both can be valid depending on what packages you install.